# Problema com script?

Tags: autohotkey

Gostaria de tentar solucionar o meu problema.
Fiz um SCRIPT no programa AUTOHOTKEY no qual eu utilizo uma chave de combinação de UP(seta pra cima) + LEFT (seta pra esquerda) e essa combinacao ativa a tecla NumpadHome, porém a tecla UP se torna uma chave de prefixo e perde sua funcao principal.
Pesquisei e adicionei no script uma funcao que ativa junto com a chave de combinacao a funcao incial da tecla UP. Só que quando eu fiz isso a Tecla UP quando pressionada só ativa 1x.

Ex: No jogo que eu jogo, quando eu pressiona a tecla UP, o boneco fica andando pra cima ate eu soltar a tecla.

Quando eu ativo esse script e pressiono a tecla UP o boneco anda uma vez só e para, gostaria de saber se existe alguma funcao que possa incluir para que qnd eu pressionar a tecla UP, execute a funcao de andar para cima e só pare quando soltar.

Obrigado.

Segue o script abaixo:

```
Up & Left:: NumpadHome

Up:: Send  {Up}
```

Comment: Coloque * na frente do  *Up:: Send {Up}

Comment: nao funcionou =/
o que aconteceu foi q quando eu aperto a chave de combinacao up e left, o boneco fica andando sem parar, so para quando eu aperto a combinacao denovo.
o que eu queria, é que so a tecla UP , voltasse a executar a funcao normal de andar pra cima e enquanto eu mantenho a tecla pressionada.. dps q eu soltar a tecla , para.

Comment: Tentou colocar o * em ambas ou somente no up&left?

Comment: Qual o código de javascript mesmo ? Sem o código é difícil de dizer, mas tentando adivinhar, parece me a diferença entre escutar o evento `keypress` e `keydown`. No `keypress` só faz alguma coisa quando a tecla é premida e largada ao passo que no `keydown` basta a pessoa ter a tecla premida que já é interpretado

Comment: eu nao entendo muito de fazer, pesquisei muito sobre e nao consegui.. mas quando pesquisei falava sobre esse KEYDOWN.. como q eu colocaria no script isso ?

Comment: Hudson, coloquei somente onde vc pediu.

Comment: Tem que colocar um [exemplo minimo completo e vericavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para se conseguir perceber e reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score 2):

`~Up & Left:: NumpadHome`

O prefixo  `~` fará com que as teclas originais não sejam alteradas e seus envios não sejam interceptados.

Caso seja intencional o comportamento e precisa apenas da tecla Up, você pode alterar a combinação para:
`Left & Up:: NumpadHome`
Neste caso a tecla Left será desativada, mas a Up funcionará normalmente quando isoladas.